# formula !x using only x and NAND

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi how would I get formula that is equivalent to NOT X, using only the variable X and the NAND connective?

Regards

J

Comment: Why is this question tagged "calculus"?  Logical calculus of propositions, perhaps?  Perhaps someone who knows how could re-tag; or tell me how.

Comment: @RobertLewis To retag, just click the "Edit" button below the post.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson:  OK, thanks, will do!

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson:  Done!  and thanks again!

Comment: @User103388:  I re-tagged your question; hope it's OK!  Regards, RKL

Answer (score 2):

Since $\operatorname{NAND}(A, B) = \neg (A \wedge B)$, and $A \wedge A = A$,

we have $\neg X = \neg(X \wedge X) = \operatorname{NAND}(X, X)$ !

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Man, I sure wish I had a buck for every time I used this trick when I was digital circuit/logic designer, back when the *Code of Hammurabi* was first carved in cuneiform!

Comment: **NB:** The final "!" in the above is exactly that, an exclamation point, not to be confused with a (conceivably misplaced) logical connective! ;)

Comment: haha! (on a different note: had you made it even-numbered, it wouldn't matter!)

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan:  I'm sure I would find your joke a lot funnier if I got it! ;)  made what even-numbered?

Comment: What's the difference (in principle; ignoring matters of physical nature) between an even sequence of NOT gates and a piece of wire?

Comment: @HunanRostomyan:  Gotcha!  ROFL!!!

Answer (score 0):

The truth table for NOT x goes as follows:

```
 x  NOT
 F   T
 T   F
```

The truth table for NAND(x, y) goes as follows:

```
 x\y   F   T
  F    T   T
  T    T   F
```

Now just observe the diagonal:

```
 x\y   F   T
  F    T
  T        F
```

In other words, we have that NAND(F, F)=T, and NAND(T, T)=F.  Thus, if p=q, NAND(p, q)=NOT(p)=NOT(q)=NAND(p, p)=NAND(q, q).  So, NAND(x)=NOT(x).